# Porque é que acham que esta pergunta é baseada em opiniões?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica

Porque é que acham que esta pergunta é baseada em opiniões?

[Desenvolvimento mobile multiplataforma](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/desenvolvimento-mobile-multiplataforma)

Ela pode gerar respostas baseadas em opiniões, mas acredito que dá para responder isso de forma concreta se alguém fizer testes aos *framework's*.

O que acham?

Comment: Minha pergunta sobre java quase teve um destino parecido, marcada  como duplicata de javascript, com votos para fechar(2). Seria um padrão? Acho que deveriam dar mais tempo antes de suspende-la.

Comment: @Florida aproveita e coloca o link dela aqui.

Comment: Boa ideia, só não queria desviar o foco do tópico. Segue o [link](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/69771/como-reduzir-o-tamanho-de-um-vari%C3%A1vel-passada-via-post-compactando-a).

Comment: @Florida acho que essa pergunta é um problema específico com resposta. A pergunta que é colocada aqui é bem mais geral. Ela pede: _"Qual desses framework's possui a melhor desempenho e menor curva de aprendizado"_

Comment: @Florida fechar ou suspender não é deletar é apenas para evitar receber respostas enquanto a pergunta não estiver nos "conformes", leia: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2676/3635 só não liga para a ultima parte da resposta lá-- é apenas uma piada rs -- nota sobre a sua pergunta, ela quase foi fechada por que não tinha código/detalhes então era um pouco dificil deduzir qual era a linguagem, já que a tag android-studio se refere ao IDE e não a tecnologia.

Comment: Entendi, também concordo com isso, o que foi tenso é saber que uma pergunta sobre _java_ foi marcada como possível duplicata de _javascript_, me veio a mente se leram o post, não estava muito claro como agora, mas eram coisas totalmente distintas. É preciso mais atenção.

Comment: @Florida então, não há problema, pode haver falta de atenção de ambos lados, tanto do autor da pergunta quanto de quem fechou ela. A vantagem do StackOverflow é que sempre podemos reabrir as perguntas, a ideia é só impedir "respostas erradas" por exemplo. :)

Comment: Compreendo, eu mesmo pensei em fecha-la, mas decidi manter, mesmo que seja fechada ou qualquer coisa, se alguém tiver a mesma duvida já tem por onde começar. =)

Comment: @Florida pessoalmente eu acho que a sua pergunta está boa depois da sua 6 edição, logo conseguiremos resolver.

Comment: @Florida O que aconteceu com a sua pergunta foi realmente falta de atenção dos usuários ao ler a pergunta. Eu sei que a informação estava na tag, mas isso significa que ela é invisível para alguns usuários que não prestam atenção a todos os detalhes. Este é o motivo porque alguns usuários colocam a tecnologia no título da pergunta (o que também não seria adequado). Para evitar esse tipo de confusão em suas próximas perguntas, descreva explicitamente as tecnologias que está usando e as características relevantes do projeto. Mas não se preocupe muito, com o tempo você pega o jeito.

Comment: @utluiz realmente estava escrito a tecnologia como você disse, o Florida não errou, mas como existem aplicativos baseados em "webview", fiquei na duvida então votei por fechar para evitar possíveis problemas, no momento que me deparei que estava tudo nos conformes eu retirei o voto.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Esta pergunta é um dos muitos casos limítrofes entre o que é simplesmente opinião ou uma opinião técnica embasada.

Do meu ponto de vista, a forma da pergunta tem alguns problemas. Por exemplo, acho que é impossível definir qual tem melhor desempenho. Isso depende muito para que você usa. Aliás, mesmo que haja diferenças absolutas no desempenho, isso é realmente relevante para um app comum se considerar o benefício que a tecnologia traz?

Além disso, é impossível dizer qual tem a menor curva de aprendizado. Isso depende completamente do *background* de cada profissional. Muitos frameworks são evoluções de tecnologias específicas, então quem tiver mais familiaridade com certas técnicas e padrões terá maior facilidade com tecnologias similares.

Do jeito que está, é melhor ficar suspensa, mas creio ser possível salvar a pergunta se o AP definir com mais exatidão o que ele precisa e critérios para comparação entre os frameworks.

Vou tentar orientar o AP através de um comentário e ver se ele nos dá as informações necessárias para criar boas respostas.

Comment: É por aquele comentário que se vê a tua qualidade como moderador, parabéns @utluiz.

Answer (score 6):

Eu fui um dos que suspendi pelo fato de considerar que cada pessoa tem uma familiaridade e ou facilidade com um tipo de ambiente, levando em consideração que as duvidas não são só sobre `html`, `css`, `js` (tecnologias dos tais frameworks), mas também sobre as **IDEs**.

Por exemplo eu considero Java para um iniciante um pouco mais difícil, no entanto tenho um colega de trabalho que não tem dificuldade com java, porém com PHP ele se atrapalha todo.

Em outras palavras, a experiencia que cada *ambiente (de desenvolvido)* proporciona pode variar de pessoa para pessoa, fora que com isto podem surgir respostas como eu *"eu gosto de X"*, mesmo não tendo trabalhado com outros ambientes.

### Motivos pelo qual acho que não podemos responder

1. Performance: "Talvez" seja possível definir, mas não é tão fácil.
2. Grau de aprendizagem: Cada um se adapta a um tipo de ambiente melhor que o outro, não tem como definir.

Eu considero que o autor da pergunta deveria experimentar os mais acessíveis (fáceis de instalar) e por si mesmo decidir qual lhe parece mais interessante.

A minha opinião é **não existem atalhos**

> Existir atalhos pode até existir, mas sempre haverá um problema que para quem usa atalhos será uma dor de cabeça.

Claro que é possível que possa haver uma resposta e eu posso estar totalmente engando sobre a pergunta especifica.

Comment: +1 pelo segundo motivo.

Comment: @rray o primeiro estava confuso mesmo rs. Editei :) Obrigado pelo +1